# Error found loading /etc/profile Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Help! I started having this error after i fixed some broken files or something like that while i was trying to download glibc 2.30
Every time i turn on the computer this error apears

```
Error found loading /etc/profile

usr/share/im-config/xinputrc.common: line 24: command not found
usr/share/im-config/xinputrc.common: line 24: command not found
```

As a result the sessin will not be configured correctly
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible

Now i can't open the terminal nethier change the language
Also when i start the PC the thing that has to options of flashing the computer dosent apear nethier anymore, what do i do?

Comment: This is hard because I have no idea what you mean by "*Lib9*" and no packages exist of that name (very few (if any) use upper-case characters anyway) or "lib9" (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lib9&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).  If you made package changes, you can search `/var/apt/apt/history.log` to remind you of what you did (so you can tell us), or explore you command `history` etc.

Comment: It was glibc 2.30, I just corrected it.  Is that I did not remember the name

Comment: What release are you using?  That is an *eoan* package, and Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   You may have corrupted your system if it wasn't *eoan*  (I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to check your status)

Comment: Possibly useful is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152408/how-to-fix-broken-glibc-packages

Comment: Text terminal may work, however you've added a core *eoan* component, and your system isn't fully *bionic* any-longer (ie. a *frankensystem*) which was the purpose of `ubuntu-support-status` (ie. get a feel for the damage you've done, and select your fix, be it restoration of data from backups etc)

Comment: Hey thanks for trying to help me, today i reseted my Ubuntu and was able to fix the problem!